# Using Close Command in Method

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am trying to fire a command to close my page after finalizing the execution of a method. However, the Close() command is not working.

According to the code below, how do I close my view after finishing the method execution?

My Model:

```
        public IMvxCommand BtnSaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxAsyncCommand(updateOrder);
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> updateOrder()
    {
        var errors = validator.Validate(this);

        if (!errors.IsValid)
        {
            messageService.showMessage(errors);

            return false;
        }
        var responseEdit = await orderService.update(configureOrder());

        if (responseEdit == null)
        {
            messageService.showMessage("Pedido " + Item.id + " foi editado com sucesso.");

            configureUpdateItem();

            //Close View
            Close(this);
        }
        else
        {
            messageService.showMessage((IErrorCollection)responseEdit);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**--Update**

Adding more information, when triggered the Close(this) command I get the following error:

Mvx: Warning: 325,38 Do not know how to close this viewmodel - topmost view does not present this viewmodel

Answer (score 2):

You need to call DismissViewController() on the NavigationController

Comment: But this command I use only controller, right? I need to close the view of the Model